# Как вывести web-страницу в jpeg?

Tags: php, html, jpeg

Сейчас страница с помощью php генерируется в html виде. картинки, текст, яндекс-карты. 
Как это все вывести в jpeg?

Comment: PhantomJS вам поможет. Либо можно пользоваться сторонними сервисами типа url2png

Comment: это же просто скриншот?

Comment: Одно дело скриншот со всеми окнами вокруг, а другое дело скриншот только страницы. Разве не это Вам надо?

Comment: качество скриншотов меня не устраивает. Поэтому думаю, что можно как-то по другому вывести.

Comment: да не скриншот это. Это snapshot страницы, после того как браузер пропарсит ее. И качество картинки указываете Вы в настройках. Но дело хозяйское, может действительно кто что другое подскажет. Удачи.